# Jenkins Ec2 plugin fails during configuration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have installed latest ec2-plugin in jenkins

I am getting below error during configuration in Jenkins ,AWS ACCESS,SECRET Key is having proper rights

Jenkins version : 2.73
EC2 plugin : 1.37

Error in Jenkins :

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1164)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:762)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:724)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.doInvoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:14388)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.invoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:14364)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.executeDescribeRegions(AmazonEC2Client.java:7622)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.describeRegions(AmazonEC2Client.java:7598)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.describeRegions(AmazonEC2Client.java:7634)
    at hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud$DescriptorImpl.doFillRegionItems(AmazonEC2Cloud.java:157)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
Caused: javax.servlet.ServletException
```

Comment: Have you taken any steps to remedy the issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please paste your error message into the text so that is easier to read and can be found through search engines. Thanks.